# Lenovo T470p Intel 8265 wifi hard blocked Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless

I'm running Kubuntu 17.10 on a Lenovo T470p that has an Intel 8265 wifi card. Here's my lspci:

```
van@t470p:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x4) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a171 (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (5) I219-V (rev 31)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a808
```

Here's my rfkill list:

```
van@t470p:~$ sudo rfkill list
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
4: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Here is the output of dmesg:

```
van@t470p:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[sudo] password for syd: 
[    9.627594] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    9.639912] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-33.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.640024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-32.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.643239] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 31.560484.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    9.661914] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    9.720995] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: f8:34:41:da:a3:c7
[    9.805758] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

I don't seem to have iwlwifi-8265-33 or iwlwifi-8265-32 in my /lib/firmware:

```
van@t470p:/lib/firmware$ sudo find ./ -name "*8265*"
./iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode
./iwlwifi-8265-21.ucode
./iwlwifi-8265-27.ucode
./iwlwifi-8265-31.ucode
```

Could this be why it's "hard locked" on start up?

The really annoying thing is that everything was working just fine before I had to perform a clean install.

I've tried the obvious FN + F8 and FN + F10 key combinations. Not sure if there's another key combination on this laptop to turn wifi on/off.

My question is: how do I remove the "hard block" so I can fire up my wifi?

Comment: On my similar T440p, it is F8 alone, not Fn+F8. Please try that.

Comment: Thanks so much @chili555, that did the trick (I feel quite foolish now). I've rebooted quite a few times, and wifi works each time. I've also noticed that WiFi is now automatically disabled when you plug in an ethernet cable - not sure if this has always been the case, but found it very interesting. PS - not sure how to mark your answer as the answer.

Comment: I'm glad it's working by whatever means. Network Manager will default to ethernet if it's available, effectively disabling wireless, because ethernet is generally faster and more secure.